# What is the difference between @(posedge clk) begin end.... and @(posedge clk);?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What is the difference between the following 2 code segments:

```
forever begin
    @posedge(clk) begin // no semi-colon
        if(vif.sof == 1) begin
             //some code here
        end
    end
 end

forever begin
    @posedge(clk); // <- with semi-colon
        if(vif.sof == 1) begin
           //some code here
        end
end
```

Does the `begin..end` that goes with `@(posedge clk)` make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

event_controls like `@` and `#` in procedural code are not statement by themselves; they are prefixes to the statements that follow. And a *statement* can be a simple statement, like an assignment, or a block like begin/end or fork/join. And a block is allowed wherever a single statement is allowed.

When you write `@(posedge clk);` it is really `@(posedge clk) null_statement;`

I should have given you enough information to answer your question, but here is another variation:

```
forever 
        @posedge(clk)
        if(vif.sof == 1) begin
           //some code here
        end
```

Now there is a big difference if a semicolon follows `@(posedge clk)` or not.